# 'will' and 'be going to' which is correct?

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense, will-vs-going-to

I'm not a native-speaker, so sometimes future tense (be going to, will) is tricky to me.

a. If it rains this weekend, I'm gonna stay home.
 
b. If it rains this weekend, I will stay home.

c. If this happens again, they're gonna lose everything. 
d. If this happens again, they will lose everything.

I wrote some sentences with be going to and will. So, which are correct in these sentences? All of them correct or interchangeable? Are some awkward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both structures are possible, depending on what you want to say.

*Will* is used for:

- decisions made at the moment of speaking (e.g. I'll open the door!)
- predictions (I think it will be cold)
- offers or willingness (I will stay at home if it rains - will shows your willingness)
- requests (will you do me a favor?)
- firm intentions, promises (I will always love you)
- threats (I will kill you!)
- facts about the future (Christmas will fall on Monday next year)

*To be going to* is used for:

- intentions, plans (I'm going to stay at home if it rains)
- saying that something in the future is possible because of something in the present (It's going to snow)
- predictions, especially when there is evidence (this building is going to collapse - it's so old!)